# Why does the read-back pixel color differ from color drawn on a QImage?

Tags: qt, qpainter, qimage

I have a problem with `QPainter` on `QImage` in Qt 5.4.

The image has `Format_ARGB32`. I want to set a given RGBA value on pixels in the image using a `QPainter` draw function and later read the value back using `QImage::pixel`.

Yet the value painted and the value read back are different. What am I doing wrong?

Sample code:

```
QImage image(100, 100, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
uint value = 0x44fa112b; //some value..
QPainter painter(&image);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMo de_Source);
QColor color(qRed(value), qGreen(value), qBlue(value), qAlpha(value));
QBrush brush(color);
painter.setBrush(brush);
painter.drawRect(0,0,image.width(), image.height());

uint value1 = image.pixel(50,50);
// value1 IS NOT EQUAL TO value. Why??
```

Comment: Note that to fill an image with a value you can just use QImage::fill. Then, what's the value that you get in the end?

Comment: Fill is working properly (color value returned is the same used for fill). But in my case I have different values to be painted on the image and read back; not a single value. Any idea?

Comment: The code as posted (with composition mode `QPainter::CompositionMode_Source`) works as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in Qt 5.7. Perhaps earlier Qt versions need the `painter.end()` call.

```
#include <QtGui>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QGuiApplication app{argc, argv};
   QImage image{100, 100, QImage::Format_ARGB32};
   auto const set = 0x44fa112b;
   QPainter painter(&image);
   painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
   painter.setBrush({{qRed(set), qGreen(set), qBlue(set), qAlpha(set)}});
   painter.drawRect(image.rect());
   if (false) painter.end(); //<< try with true here
   auto readback = image.pixel(50,50);
   qDebug() << hex << set << readback;
   Q_ASSERT(readback == set);
}
```

Comment: I tried with painter.end() also. There is no diff.                                      For input value =  "44fa112b" output value =  "44fb1329"

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!!
Working properly when I tried with Qt 5.8
Looks like a bug with Qt 5.4.
Thanks to all :)**